# Test either the following series is convergent or not : $(\cos{1})+(\cos{2})^2+(\cos{3})^3+(\cos{4})^4+...+(\cos{n})^n+...$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Actually, I have tried in many ways, first of all for test of absolute convergence, but as the sequence $\{\cos{(n)}\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$, hence many of the tests will not respond, and if $\{S(n)\}$ is the sequence of partial sum of the given series, then I tried to show that one of it's subsequences may diverge, as because I have tested some $S(n)$, but they are switching positive and off positive, hence I think it will diverge .

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2684857/does-sum-n-1-infty-sinnn-converge?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Not worth much but the series DOES converge to around 10.65 surprisingly: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n+%3D+1+to+infinity+of+(cos(n))%5En

Not sure how to show to the convergence myself though

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Just because WA gives a value doesn't mean it converges. It evaluates it numerically. If the growth is slow enough it can think it has converged without this being the case. Try for example [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n+%3D+1+to+infinity+of+(sin(n))%5En) and compare with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2684912/147873). The fact that $\sum \sin(n)^n$ diverges probably means this series also diverges (the same argument can likely be extended to this case, but I haven't checked this).

Comment: Huh. My bad then, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Regardless if it converges, Jack would probably be the expert of explaining why.

Comment: There is some uniform sampling theorem for periodic functions involving an integral you can probably use.

Comment: Thanks, Robert Z , I have seen the answer, and the trick actually, I think it can be done only using the Dirichlet's irrationality criterion, in almost the same way, actually.

Comment: Maybe testing whether the sequence is cauchy can help.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898385/when-does-the-limit-cosnfn-converges-as-n-rightarrow-infty-n-in/2901343#2901343